# Cell value wont change on new Column

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview

No matter what I do, I cant set a cell's value using this:

```
row.Cells["columnName"].Value = "some text";
```

I am filling a DatagridView with a Datatable as its source. But with a certain column I want the user to be able to use a dropdown to change the value. So I am Hiding the column that gets generated by the datasource, then making a new comboBox column, adding in items then transferring the values from the hidden column.

```
  private void ShotsDGV()
        {
            // if there is data, clear the DGV and let the data create its own columns
            if (shotsData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                shotsDataGrid.Columns.Clear();
                
                // set new column as a dropdown column
                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn newSequenceColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                
                // Assign the data from the datatable to the DGV
                shotsDataGrid.DataSource = shotsData;

                //Hide the Auto Generated Column
                //shotsDataGrid.Columns["Sequence"].Visible = false;

                // Set the Header Text of the New Column            
                newSequenceColumn.HeaderText = "Sequence";

                // Set the Name of the New Column
                newSequenceColumn.Name = "newSequenceHeader";

                //get the Items from the other dataTable and add all of the options for the Dropdown
                for (int i = 0; i < seqData.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    newSequenceColumn.Items.Add(seqData.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                }

                // add this new column to the DGV
                shotsDataGrid.Columns.Add(newSequenceColumn);

                //set the new column to be in the right position
                shotsDataGrid.Columns["newSequenceHeader"].DisplayIndex = 2;

                // copy data from original column
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in shotsDataGrid.Rows)
                {
                    row.Cells["newSequenceHeader"].Value = row.Cells["Sequence"].Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(row.Cells["newSequenceHeader"].Value + " - Tada! ");

                }       
            }
        }
```

I get no errors, and the console write I have directly after says that the value *is* set... but its just not adding the value in the actual Cell in the window... It is working as a dropdown with my options added, but the cell is blank until I manually select from the drop down. I can also set ANY other cell in any OTHER column using the same method and it works fine, but this new column I have created just wont be set.

Strangely, I have copied this code from another DataGridView using the exact same technique, and that one works perfectly. I cant understand why this new column, created the exact same way wont allow me to set any values in it.

Comment: Is `row.Cells["newSequenceHeader"].Value` a `string`?

Comment: Well, technically its type is DataGridViewComboBoxCell. At least that's what I get when I do a GetType() on it.  But I have tried just setting the column to being a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and I still couldn't put a value in it with code.

Comment: I mean what type does return `.Value`, not `row.Cells["newSequenceHeader"]`?

Comment: Im trying this: `Console.WriteLine(row.Cells["newSequenceHeader"].Value.GetType());` and getting exception error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: What do you get by `row.Cells["Sequence"].Value.GetType()`?

Comment: Same exception error - I should point out that I have tried just setting it with a string directly: `row.Cells["newSequenceHeader"].Value = "test";` - This also has no affect

Comment: Was "test" also among ComboBox Items?

Comment: No, but I did also try a value from comboBox options and also tried simplifying the column to a textboxCell. It just won't set...I feel like I'm going crazy...

Comment: I am not understanding why you would need to “hide” the “Sequence” column. What data is stored in the original data source that prevents you from mapping the “Sequence” column to an added combo box column using the combo columns `DataPropertyName`? Setting up the combo box column is obviously some extra work, but it can be done without hiding the original column as you describe. Can you elaborate as to why you need to hide this column instead of “using” it? This would eliminate all the code you have to maintain the two columns.

Comment: Thanks John. I was under the impression that you can't modify the column type if its created by a data source. Im hiding the original so the user only sees my manually made combo. If you have a way of converting my original column so I can just add a few extra items and make it a combo, then as you say, this would solve my problem

Comment: When you add a combo box column to a `DataGridView` and then “map” that column to the grids underlying data source… there is one utmost import thing you need to check “before” the code “binds” the grids data source to the grid to avoid the grids dreaded `DataError` when binding… it is wise to check and make sure that for each row in the data source that the cell/property pointed to by the combo box column IS one of the items in the combo box columns list of items.

Comment: In other words, after you fill the combo box columns list of items… and then bind the data source to the grid, if at least one (1) “item” value in the data source is NOT in the combo box columns list of “items” then you will get an app ending `DataError.` Bear in mind, the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` is a different monster than a regular combo box. With a regular combo box, invalid values would just be ignored.

Comment: Therefore, to make sure this does NOT happen, it is prudent to check the data source values “before” it is bound to the grid. What you do if an item in the data source is NOT in the combo box columns list of items is a decision you would have to make. You will NOT be able to “ignore” this problem “item.” You will either have to “remove” that row from the data source… OR… “add” that item to the combo box columns list of items. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I can give a small example of how to set this up, however, it would make sense to see if this is something that can help you to eliminate “hiding” the column. I will not deny that it can be very frustrating when binding a grids combo box column to a data source. This is why IMHO; you MUST check the data source for these problems “before” you bind it.

Comment: Thanks for all that info John. Binding the column to the data source sounds like a much better way. I just dont know how to di it... I'm learning all this as I go... I can say that the data being 'wrong' wont be a problem as I will be populating the data from another source and I intend on making the dropdown the only user input for this column, so there should never be a way for the data not to match. Can you point me in the right direction to get started with "mapping" the data? I am currently just saying `dgv.datasource = data` and letting it fly....

Comment: OK, so that was much easier that I thought it was going to be. Just as you said, I made sure the DataPropertyName matched and it treated my comboBox column as the correct column to use for my original 'sequence' data. When I first mapped all the data, it was making a duplicate, so I went forward thinking that was just what it did... I think I was also only setting name NOT DataPropertyName - so all good now! THANK YOU

Comment: I am glad you got the column working properly. However, I somewhat disagree with your comment… _”so there should never be a way for the data not to match”_ … this may well be true; however, the consequences are too high. The code will crash and become unusable until fixed. I am just saying that I do not share your confidence that the data will NEVER change. If the error was not an app ending “crash” then I would agree that we could just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the Advice. I will make sure to add some error checking as you suggest